# Primefaces contextMenu for multiple dataTables?

Tags: primefaces, datatable, contextmenu

Is it possible to have a contextMenu that pertains to multiple dataTables? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I have never done it but I would try it like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="table1" ...>
    <p:ajax event="contextMenu" update="myContextMenuId" listener="#{myContextMenuBL.initContextMenuForTable('table1')}" oncomplete="PF('myContextMenuWidgetVar').show(currentEvent);" />
</p:dataTable>

<p:dataTable id="table2" ...>
    <p:ajax event="contextMenu" update="myContextMenuId" listener="#{myContextMenuBL.initContextMenuForTable('table2')}" oncomplete="PF('myContextMenuWidgetVar').show(currentEvent);" />
</p:dataTable>

<p:contextMenu id="myContextMenuId" widgetVar="myContextMenuWidgetVar">
    <p:menuitem value="entry 1"  />
    ...
</p:contextMenu>
```

In your context menu controller you know for which table the menu is "working" with the call of `initContextMenuForTable()`. If you want different context menus for each table it will be a little more difficult. But why you not only use a separate context menu for each table?

Comment: Cool I'll give this a go. I did try to use a separate context menu for each table but then only the final table rendered would have a fully functional context menu...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "only the final table rendered would have a fully functiona context menu". I think a separate menu could be easier for each table using the `for` attribute of the `contextMenu` points to the table.

Comment: Yes, this is the logic I had as well. However, despite pointing a context menu to a specific table, only the last table had a context menu which, when an item was selected, would render the appropriate page. Perhaps something to do with lazy loading?

Comment: Ok, tried this. I think previously I was naming things a bit wrong. Feeling fairly certain I've now pointed things to each other correctly, I have the strange behaviour that sometimes one table's context menu works and the rest fail, other times another one does and the rest fail... bit odd